# Inheritance and visibility of interfaces

Tags: oop, inheritance, kotlin, interface

The task is to hide Library1 interface1 behind the facade of Library2.

Full source here https://bitbucket.org/tim4dev/inheritance-interfaces/src/master/

1. (Library1) interface1
2. (Library2) interface2 : interface1
3. (Library2) Klass2: Interface2
4. (application)

```
implementation project(":library2")
class KlassApp constructor(
    private val klass: Interface2
) {
    fun klassAppFun() {
        klass.interface1fun1()
    }
}
```

We get an error

`KlassApp.kt: Unresolved reference: interface1fun1`

**Question**: what are the standard patterns to hide `Library1` behind the facade of `Library2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose:

1. make `Library1` an `api` dependency of `Library2`, not `implementation` [as you currently have it](https://bitbucket.org/tim4dev/inheritance-interfaces/src/0080e0973defe57ac258c71145799a54af92801a/library2/build.gradle#lines-35) (so not hide it fully);
2. if you want to hide it, you can't expose any types of `Library1` in public parts of `Library2`, which includes extending its interfaces.

See [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) for the difference of `api` and `implementation`:

> So when should you use the api configuration? An API dependency is one that contains at least one type that is exposed in the library binary interface, often referred to as its ABI (Application Binary Interface). This includes, but is not limited to:
>
> - **types used in super classes or interfaces**
> - types used in public method parameters, including generic parameter types (where public is something that is visible to compilers. I.e. , public, protected and package private members in the Java world)
> - types used in public fields
> - public annotation types